# Construct SQL SELECT query out of multiple PHP GET parameters

Tags: php, sql, select, parameters, get

I'm using the code provided in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203351/1711950 to handle different combinations of SQL WHERE clauses:

```
$vars = array(
    (!empty($_GET["var1"]))? " keyword = '". $_GET["var1"] ."' ": null, 
    (!empty($_GET["var2"]))? " author  = '". $_GET["var2"] ."' ": null,
    (!empty($_GET["var3"]))? " date    = '". $_GET["var3"] ."' ": null,
    (!empty($_GET["var4"]))? " forums  = '". $_GET["var4"] ."' ": null
);


function myfilterarray($var)
{
    return !empty($var)?$var: null;
}

$newvars = array_filter($vars, 'myfilterarray');

$where = join(" OR ", $newvars);

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT title, description FROM table ".(($where)?"WHERE ".$where: null);

echo $sql;
```

The code works when each GET parameter is a single value like this:

http://example.com/getData.php?keyword=a1

I want to be able to handle this scenario:

http://example.com/getData.php?keyword=a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2

Therefor I've modified the code like this:

```
(!empty($_GET["var1"]))? " keyword IN ('". $_GET["var1"] ."') ": null
```

That off course makes the SQL query look like this, 
which won't work because of the quotations.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword IN ('SE162321000156-3PQZ,SE2321000164-7381037592311')
```

How could I get around this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: you try to get rows from database where keyword exactly is 'SE162321000156-3PQZ,SE2321000164-7381037592311'. As fast and dirty workaround you can use `$in = "'".preg_replace('/,/',"','",$v)."'"`    or    `$in = "'".implode("','",explode(',',$v))."'";`

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split the values , put quotation marks around them and concatenate the string back together. This is a very very basic example:

```
$foo = (!empty($_GET["keyword"]))? $_GET["keyword"] : null;
$foo = explode(",", $foo);
$fooArray = [];
foreach( $foo as $fooElement ) {
    $fooArray[] = "'$fooElement'";
}
$foo = implode(",", $fooArray);

echo $foo; // output: 'a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2'
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gave me ''a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2'' though.

Comment: Mhm not if I execute the exact same code as I've posted it. Did you change sth.?

Comment: I don't now what "sth." is but I changed "keyword" to the parameter I'm using.

Comment: Ah! Yes, you don't need the quation marks at the end and the beginning of the sql string: `keyword IN (". $foo .")` should do the trick as the elements are already wrapped

Comment: btw "sth." = something :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = explode(",",trim($_GET["var1"]));
$var = "";
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr);$i++)
{
    if($i == (sizeof($arr)-1))
    {
        $var .= "'".$arr[$i]."'";
    }
    else
    {
        $var .= "'".$arr[$i]."',";
    }
}
```

Now you can use `$var` inside your query, i.e IN($var)

Comment: Thanks, but that gave me

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' on line 3

Comment: @RawlandHustle I have re-edited the code. Kindly check.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me. I have pasted the whole code I've taken from another question/answer. Could you put your code in it like it supposed to be?